# Return the value of edges from given set of vertices with value

Tags: python, depth-first-search

You are currently trying to investigate the property of valency in a molecule.
Here, valency is the number of bonds joining an atom to its neighboring atoms. Precisely speaking, given some positive N integers, you want to know whether there can be a molecule whose valency numbers of atoms are same to the integers while satisfying the given conditions.

1) Each atom is joined by at least one bond, and there can be multiple bonds
between two atoms.

2) A molecule is connected, that is, there is a path composed of bonds between every pair of atoms in a molecule.

3) There is no bond between an atom and itself.

For given list(that represents valency of atoms) of N elements, You should return N by N matrix that represents the number of bonds between atoms if such molecule exists. M[ i ][ j ] means the number of bonds between atom i and atom j. If such molecule could not exist, return None. **You must use depth-first-search.**

For example, if [20, 30, 30] is given, you should return [[0, 10, 10], [10, 0, 20], [10, 20, 0]]. If [10, 10, 30] is given, return None.

Comment: I would recommend you have a look at this post: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1044698), because people won't just write the answer for you

Comment: Just curious, wondering if the solution is unique?

Comment: @pok fung Chan The solution may not be unique

Comment: @Energya Thank you for letting me know. I have asked only 2-3 questions on this site, I didn't know there was a guideline for homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

Found this problem interesting. I came up with a solution, though not depth-first-search. Just a brute force method:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations as comb

def findmolecule(v):
    if sum(v) % 2 == 1:
        return None
    n = np.size(v)
    M = np.zeros([n,n])
    total = sum(v)
    varsize = int(n*(n-1)/2)
    for com in comb(range(1,total//2), varsize-1):
        x, y = 0,0
        counter = 0
        partition = [0 for _ in range(varsize)]
        partition[0] = com[0]
        partition[-1] = total//2 - com[-1]
        for i in range(1,varsize-1):
            partition[i] = com[i] - com[i-1]
        while counter < varsize:
            y += 1
            if y == n:
                x += 1
                y = x+1
            M[x,y] = partition[counter]
            M[y,x] = partition[counter]
            counter += 1
        if all(sum(M) == v):
            return M
    return None

matrix = findmolecule([20,30,30])
print(matrix) if matrix is not None else print('None')
matrix = findmolecule([10,10,30])
print(matrix) if matrix is not None else print('None')
matrix = findmolecule([20,32,26,24])
print(matrix) if matrix is not None else print('None')
```

I just use the fact that

1. sum of the matrix column = vector
2. the matrix is symmetric

Then I listed all the possible symmetric matices and check whether they fulfill the first condition. Look forward to other solutions!